# Is it secure to do "chroot" SFTP directory without actually setting owner to be root?

Tags: security, sftp

I don't know if this sounds wrong, but I have a use case where I need to run a cron job and rsync the data into the SFTP file directory.

Typically SFTP set up on the Internet would suggest to set the permission on the file directory to be own by `root:SFTP_USER_GROUP`.

In my case I restrict all users in `SFTP_USER_GROUP` to be read-only (by removing the `w` bit). But since I need to rsync data to SFTP file directory, the only way I can do that is as root. But I don't want to run cron job as root - that sounds really dangerous.

So my question is whether it is okay to "chroott" the permission to be `SFTP_USER:SFTP_READ_ONLY_GROUP`, so I can execute the cron job as `SFTP_USER`.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to reach for my trusty POSIX ACLs: `setfacl -m u:someone:rwx /home/user`.  However, you may also want to consider making a subdirectory inside the `chroot`ed directory to put the files into; that will remove the strict "root-only" requirement on the `chroot` path that SSH imposes.